# Java multi-dimensional array with only specifying t

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

In Java, below line to create a multi-dimensional array compiles fine. But does/can this array have any use as it is? It's not possible to access say, somearray[0][0], because the second array is null.

```
String[][] somearray = new String[2][];
```

Is it possible to resize it or only by creating a new String array? For example:

```
somearray = new String[2][2];
```

Answer (score 3):

That's correct

```
String[][] somearray = new String[2][];
```

will have null at both the indexes
somearray[0] and somearray[1] will be null

Since this is a two dimensional array, you can change the individual arrays at the two indexes, for example,

```
somearray[0] = new String[2];
somearray[1] = new String[2];
```